# push and length array operation, iterating through an array

Tags: javascript, livecode

I have the following code snippets in JavaScript

```
myArr = []; 
myArr.push(3); 
myArr.push(5); 
myArr.push(11); 

// console.log(myArr.length)

le = myArr.length;
for (var i=0; i < le; i++) {
     elem = myArr[i];
     // ...  e.g.
     console.log(elem)
```

}

How does a translation to LiveCode look like? Or to put it in other words - how do I emulate a *push element to array operation* and ask for *the length of an array*?

**Note**: LiveCode seems to support associative arrays only and I have not found a "Cheat sheet" yet of implemented array operations.

#### Comment on the answers

The first answer was given by Mark. It gives the general idea how to do it. Alex then made the code to work. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution from Mark is not quite correct; you can't use 'push' as the handler name, because 'push' is a reserved word in Livecode; in the code below, I've changed it to use "mypush"

Also, your version won't work correctly, because you put the declaration of 'myArray' inside the 'mouseup' handler - which makes the global array accessible within that handler only. So further on, when you access 'myArray' within the 'push' handler, you are actually declaring a local, implicitly declared variable.

Here's a version of the code changed to account for both those problems, which does (appear) to work properly.

```
global myArray
on mouseUp
   mypush 3  
   mypush 5  
   mypush 7
   repeat for each key myKey in myArray
      put myArray[myKey] & cr after msg
   end repeat
end mouseUp

on mypush elem
   local myMaxKey
   put item 2 of the extents of myArray into myMaxKey
   put elem into myArray[myMaxKey+1]
end mypush
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for this:

```
repeat for each key myKey in myArray
  put myArray[myKey] & cr after msg
end repeat
```

You don't need all that fancy JS stuff.

If you have a numeric array, you could do this:

```
put item 2 of the extents of myArray into myMaxKey
put "something" into myArray[myMaxKey+1]
```

That would simulate a push command in JS. You can also do this in a different way:

```
on mouseUp
   put "a,b,c" into myArray
   split myArray by comma
   put the keys of myArray
   combine myArray by tab
   put tab & "d" after myArray
   split myArray by tab
   put cr & cr & the keys of myArray after msg
end mouseUp
```

If you want to "emulate push notifications", you can do the following:

```
local lArray
on mouseUp
  xpush 3
  xpush 5
  xpush 7
  repeat for each key myKey in lArray
     put lArray[myKey] & cr after field 1
  end repeat
end mouseUp

on xpush theElem
   local myMaxKey
   put item 2 of the extents of lArray into myMaxKey
   put theElem into lArray[myMaxKey+1]
end xpush
```

Note that lArray is declared outside all handlers while myMaxKey is declared inside the push handler, even though both are local variables.

Comment: +1... the only thing I could add is you can also get length via the number of elements of myArray

Comment: Maybe we can also add "repeat for each element anElement in myArray" which loops through every element in the array

Comment: To clarify: If you use "for each element anElement ..." in the first code above, anElement will become the same as myArray[myKey]: "put anElement & cr after msg"

Comment: Monte, extents and number of elements is not the same. Surely, you could, but I'm not sure it would be better.

Comment: Hliljegren, I would like that too.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have added it into the question. The iteration works, but the push operation not yet. In addition it is noteworthy that the array is declared implicitly by first starting to use it with array syntax.

Comment: What do you need "emulated push operation" for? I don't understand. This seems something you don't need in LiveCode. Please, explain why you would need it. Rather than adding my answer to your question, you might want to just discuss it in the comments here and I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: Your new script in the question is wrong. You declare the global array only inside the mouseUp handler. This way, the push handler doesn't know about it, unless you declare the same global variable in the push handler. If you declare a variable outside a handler, all handlers in the script will know about it.